# How do you remove RIPPLE EFFECT from a CLICKABLE TRANSPARENT CONTAINER?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, containers, ripple-effect

I want to remove the ripple effect from a transparent clickable container but no matter what I do the effect just doesn't go away, please help!

Code:

```
InkWell(
 onTap: (){print('Tapped');},
   child: Container(
     height: 200, width: 200,),)
```

Comment: The main purpose of choosing `InkWell` is to enjoy its "ripple effect". If you don't want it, use `GestureDetector` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `GestureDetector` instead:

```
GestureDetector(
 onTap: () {print('Tapped');},
   child: Container(
     height: 200, width: 200,
   ),
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

Put Following Line in Your Material App Widget ThemeData

```
highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
splashColor: Colors.transparent,
splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
```

Like

```
theme: ThemeData(
      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use it like this:

```
InkWell(
  excludeFromSemantics: true,
  canRequestFocus: false,
  enableFeedback: false,
  splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
  splashColor: Colors.transparent,
  highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
  focusColor: Colors.transparent,
  hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
  overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
  onTap: widget.onPressed,
  child: child,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GestureDetector` instead of `InkWell` because Inkwell provide by default ripple effect, So you can use GestureDetector.